# Is it possible to get code coverage without executing any code in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, code-coverage, monkeypatching

Yeah I know it's a pretty dumb question.

suppose there's a file `temp.py`where -

```
def somemethod():

## some giant code which I don't want to execute

return true
```

and now I want to unit test this code and get the coverage but I don't want to execute the code.
I tried mocking/patching, as expected only the first line is getting covered.

Is there any module or trick that can help me in achieving this??

Comment: Only if you change the definition of "code coverage". You might be able to glean some information via a static code analysis tool (not that I know of one). What's your real objective? 100% coverage from tests is not something that happens often in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comments marking clauses for exclusion coverage.
Any line with a comment of “`pragma: no cover`” is excluded. If that line introduces a clause, for example, an if clause, or a function or class definition, then the entire clause is also excluded. Here the `__repr__` function is not reported as missing:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        blah1()
        blah2()

def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
    return "<MyObject>"
```

Excluded code is executed as usual, and its execution is recorded in the coverage data as usual. When producing reports though, coverage.py excludes it from the list of missing code.
[See documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html)

In your case

```
def somemethod():  # pragma: no cover

    ## some giant code which i dont want to excecute

    return true
```